# Data driven approach to binning conditions based on a histogram

Tags: references, binning

(Please note that this is all hypothetical at this point and the data specifics should not matter that much).

Let's say I have a dataset where participants took a certain amount of time to complete a task (x-axis below). These participants naturally separated into two rough groups: those who took about 4 seconds and those who took about 11 seconds. If I want to label participants as either "slow" or "fast", how could I reasonably do this? What is this sort of binning called? What papers should I start with reading? etc.

For the purpose of this question, assume the grouping is meaningful and I have a good idea of what caused it.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is anything to do with binning as usually understood. If it's sufficient to detect the modes and the antimode between them, a graph like that you've drawn is a good method.

Comment: But if I want to label data as belonging to one group or the other, what is the best way to create a cut-off? I assume doing it by eye is insufficient and there must be some modelling technique that can do do?

Comment: Why assume that doing by eye is insufficient? A better approach would need a direct specification of the generating process. If you don't have one, then use the data directly. Any way, what is the gain from verbal labels?

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about how to [cluster univariate data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=1D+cluster)?

Comment: Clustering is all too likely to make a small group out of the rightmost tail, not what is wanted here. Working with log time or 1 / time might improve matters.